# type defenition problem. can't get rid of type any

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, casting

I need to load some widgets from template object(maybe json later). here is an example:

```
type RectangleTemplate = {
  name: 'Rectangle';
  props: {
    width: number;
    height: number;
  }
};

type ButtonTemplate = {
  name: 'Button';
  props: {
    text: string;
  }
};

type Template = ButtonTemplate | RectangleTemplate;

class Button {
  constructor(template: ButtonTemplate) {
    console.log(template.name);
  }
}

class Rectangle {
  constructor(template: RectangleTemplate) {
    console.log(template.name);
  }
}

const widgets = { Button, Rectangle }

const createWidget = (template: Template): void => {
  const ctor = widgets[template.name as keyof typeof widgets];
  const node = new ctor(template as any);
};

const template: Template = {
  name: 'Button',
  props: {
    text: 'button'
  }
}

const widget = createWidget(template);
```

Problem is in this line: `const node = new ctor(template as any);`. I can't pass argument like `template: Template` to constructor,and forced cast it as any. can't figure out how to do it right.
[ts playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGwCGA7A5gGwgFQgWzAyWGgF4oBvAKCihSTwgC4oByORVTCVgbhqhgATgHswAZxbVatAO4BLACbAAFixQBXPACMIQ-jKgqI8tCuDqtu-QIC+VW-yqhIUAEIbgwESlwEiJFDk0nQMzGweXj58AsJikpQCtCQAHhZQ4sBC8ugGUPaOVM7g0H6ExGTunt6++OWBAD6wCMjoWGUBEE7wROLiVVEoibTwPplCGogiQgAUJP4VLJE1HRUAlMMyoyjiIlgAdBgiaHN1nfv0jGt5BUU9SH3NnG3QIdvjk96z8-XhHK3cVYkDYhEZjPYQQ7HU4LEgXMLXOwOO5jYBQBSKNAQYD9YIDGoAGieAKw+RROzR8CEEAqAHUlFi0eQYb8WECIGsWAA3ERKIIAPk270pXyC6IZ2PEAG0fudLtAHlAANYQEAiABmUBcEA14sxkoAunlhXQRIpKigILIoFNvmcKlBFagQIjClQTbLFlB2WKQvKWKxltECbFRBIpEktRA0gHtNVokj7O7UXrGWKqTSSPT9cAWZ1EVQgA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, given that you should know the types of `shape`, you can add them to the `ShapeNames` type.

```
type ShapeNames = 'Rectangle' | 'Button'; // append the rest of the possible shapes
```

Secondly, create a TemplateProps type for each shape, and add them to a parent type `ShapeTemplateProps`.

```
type RectangleTemplateProps = {
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

type ButtonTemplateProps = {
  text: string;
}

// Append additional templateProps type below
type ShapeTemplateProps = RectangleTemplateProps | ButtonTemplateProps;
```

Next, assign the `ShapeTemplateProps` type to `props`.

```
type RectangleTemplate = {
  name: ShapeNames;
  props: ShapeTemplateProps;
};

type ButtonTemplate = {
  name: ShapeNames;
  props: ShapeTemplateProps;
};
```

Lastly, remove the `as any` type cast.

Comment: yep,name matches a specific set of props.

Comment: so simple solution. thank you! you are the best!